# Vue: How to wait until one method completes before firing another

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two methods on my Vue instance;

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   id: null
  },
  methods: {
   getId: function() {
     return axios.get('url')
     .then(response => response.data)
     .then(id => this.id = id)
     .catch(error => console.log(error))
   },

   foo: function() {
    console.log(this.id)
   }
 },
 mounted: function() {
 this.getId()
 this.foo()
 }
})
```

The `console.log()` logs `null` as the value because it runs before the response `getId()` has managed to set the `id` value. I know this because when I use Vue developer tools, the id is the actual value I was expecting rather than `null`.

How can I make sure `getId()` has set the value before running `this.foo()` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use JavaScript promises to achieve this. The simplest way would be to use the async/await syntax ..

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   id: null
  },
  methods: {
   getId: function() {
     return axios.get('url')
     .then(response => response.data)
     .then(id => this.id = id)
     .catch(error => console.log(error))
   },

   foo: function() {
    console.log(this.id)
   }
 },
 mounted: async function() {
   await this.getId()
   this.foo()
 }
})
```

Or you can go the old-fashioned way ..

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   id: null
  },
  methods: {
   getId: function() {
     return axios.get('url')
     .then(response => response.data)
     .then(id => this.id = id)
     .catch(error => console.log(error))
   },

   foo: function() {
    console.log(this.id)
   }
 },
 mounted: function() {
   this.getId().then(() => this.foo())
 }
})
```

Comment: I would rather avoid the async/await syntax if possible

Comment: Then you can use `this.getId().then(() => this.foo())`. See the edited answer above.

Comment: Based on your async code I managed to make it working using `then()`. Please add it to your answer so I can accept

Comment: ah, what a coincidence!

Comment: Haha indeed. Glad things worked out for you in the end :)

Comment: Can anyone please tell me why it happens? Why is the second function getting called before the first one has finished updating the state/data?

Answer (score 3):

there are a lot of things that you can do, I think it's useful to read about [Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) in JS, but a simple answer for here:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   id: null
  },
  methods: {
       getId: function(callback) {
         return axios.get('url')
         .then(response => response.data)
         .then((id) => { 
               this.id = id
               callback()
          })
         .catch(error => console.log(error))
       },

       foo: function() {
        console.log(this.id)
       }
  },
  mounted: function() {
     this.getId(() => {
        this.foo()
     })
  }
})
```

Comment: @AshleyBrown then probably something else is wrong, check out this: https://jsfiddle.net/amirdew/t8kds5ob/3/